# How to make correct query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables.

#### Table "profiles"

<kbd>`id`</kbd><kbd>`caption`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`BMW`</kbd>    
 <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`Nissan`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`Toyota`</kbd>

#### Table "tags"

<kbd>`id`</kbd><kbd>`caption`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd>    <kbd>`Red`</kbd>
 <kbd>`2`</kbd>  <kbd>`Black`</kbd>
 <kbd>`3`</kbd>  <kbd>`White`</kbd>

#### Table "tag_links"

<kbd>`id`</kbd><kbd>`profile_id`</kbd><kbd>`tag_id`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd>         <kbd>`1`</kbd>     <kbd>`1`</kbd> BMW in Red
 <kbd>`2`</kbd>         <kbd>`1`</kbd>     <kbd>`3`</kbd> BMW in White
 <kbd>`3`</kbd>         <kbd>`2`</kbd>     <kbd>`1`</kbd> Nissan in Red
 <kbd>`4`</kbd>         <kbd>`3`</kbd>     <kbd>`2`</kbd> Toyota in Black

I try to select items from *profiles* table and include some tags.
This query for example:

```
SELECT p.id, p.caption, array_to_string(array_agg(tg.caption), ',') AS tags 
FROM profiles p 
LEFT JOIN tag_links l ON l.profile_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN tags tg ON tg.id = l.tag_id
WHERE tg.id = 1 
GROUP BY p.id
```

#### Result

<kbd>`id`</kbd><kbd>`caption`</kbd><kbd>`tags`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`BMW`</kbd>    <kbd>`Red`</kbd>  Returns only one tag, not all
 <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`Nissan`</kbd> <kbd>`Red`</kbd>

But I need to get full string of tag captions for every row not just the first one as it seems that my query returns.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause expplicitly says you only want tag 1 so how can you expect others? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want find profiles where one of tags is 1 (red) and show rows, including aggregated string of all tags, linked to profile, for example:
1, BMW, Red, White

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a WHERE clausule on the entire group, that means you must use HAVING:

```
SELECT p.id, p.caption, array_to_string(array_agg(tg.caption), ',') AS tags 
FROM profiles p 
 JOIN tag_links l ON l.profile_id = p.id 
 JOIN tags tg ON tg.id = l.tag_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING array_agg(tg.id) @> ARRAY[1];
```

And don't use a LEFT JOIN when you need an INNER JOIN.

Instead of array_to_string + array_agg, you could also use string_agg:

```
SELECT p.id, p.caption, string_agg(tg.caption, ',') AS tags 
FROM profiles p 
 JOIN tag_links l ON l.profile_id = p.id 
 JOIN tags tg ON tg.id = l.tag_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING array_agg(tg.id) @> ARRAY[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for example I replace last str to `HAVING 1 = ANY(array_agg(tg.id))

Comment: = ANY() is a nice one, but limited: It's not possible to search for multiple tags, like "4 doors" or "suv".

Comment: So, and how I can add range expression such as: tg.id IN (1,2,3)

Comment: HAVING array_agg(tg.id) @> ARRAY[1,2,3];

Comment: @> should be replaced &&

Comment: Yes, depends on what you're looking for. Different operator, different result